# Append directive to my HTML by Button Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I am creating a tasklist app and I am trying to append directive html snippet to the DOM when the user **enters text** in a form and **clicks** a button. 
The form I have looks similar to this: `<input ng-model="taskName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your task..." />`

The directive I want to append is this :

```
<div class="row" id="task-row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span id="buttonCheckTask" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" ng-mouseenter="show = true" ng-mouseleave="show = false" >
        </span>
      </span> <!-- end of buttonCheckTask button -->
      <h4>{{taskName}}</h4>    <!--lined to ng-model -->
    </div>
  </div><!-- end task-row -->
```

The `{{taskName}}` above is hopefully linked to `ng-model='taskName'`.

Here is a code sample on Plunker. [Code Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/7e3TxALJd2FLMiHIYu5y?p=preview)

Comment: When thinking in angular, it's best to avoid the word *append*. In general, you should render your directive in the view and use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or `ng-show`/`hide` to conditionally show it

Comment: Your plunker is not finished, the script.js does not compile

Comment: Any specific problems or road-blocks? Your plunker seems incomplete, you don't have a directive yet.